# hibernate sql query

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to implement my very first hibernate sql query

```
public List<Subjectgrouplist> getSubjectgroups() {
    return hibernateTemplate.find("from subjectgrouplist where id > 0");
}
```

I'm trying to return all of the table. I know the where clause is not suitable, but I still tried it out. Can someone tell me how to build the query?

I aim is to print the list in jsp with foreach-tag.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304965/how-can-i-replicate-show-tables-in-hibernate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813122/get-all-table-names-set-up-in-sessionfactory

Comment: How about reading the documentation, for God's sake? It's here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql, and the first paragraph talks about case-sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<Subjectgrouplist> getSubjectgroups() {
    return hibernateTemplate.find("from SubjectGroup x where x.id > 0");
}
```

Comment: If it returns a List<Subjectgrouplist>, it should be "from Subjectgrouplist". The query of the OP is valid, except for the naming of the entity, which is case-sensitive, as class names are in Java.

Comment: I had to guess the class name. I was pretty sure it wasn't `subjectgrouplist`, so I guessed `SubjectGroup`.

Comment: I got confused because the table name is lower case, but here you don't query it. Thanx!