# Find Database size using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I need to get the database size, I am using hibernate and Java. Used this query

```
("SELECT sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 as DataBase_Size_in_MB FROM information_schema.TABLES where table_schema="+database)
```

This works fine in Mysql but hibernate gives information_schema.TABLES is not mapped error.

Comment: You have to create a nativeQuery  i think

Comment: Why use hibernate at all?  I'd just use a bog standard JDBC query.  If you're using spring, then you can use JdbcTemplate to reduce the boilerplate code.

Comment: @beny23 because am using Hibernate  in  my entire project

Comment: Hibernate and straight JDBC can live very happily together.  They are different tools for different jobs and while Hibernate can be used for a straight JDBC query, it has been designed for Object Relational Mapping, but for this particular query there's no object mapping involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using hibernate then the name after FROM hibernate tries to find out your POJO class where you would be giving mapping to DB tables.

If you want to use native SQL use use Session.createSQLQuery("");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you need but i think you could use [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) or you can use native query which i don't recommend

Comment: I have different database, need to find database size when giving database name as parameter. How to do it with Hibernate??

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304965/how-can-i-replicate-show-tables-in-hibernate) post might help